# How Do I insert Data to my monogDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using Node.js, Express.js, Passport.js, MongoDB and mongoose for building my application. I have set the user schema and model and my app now can authenticate existing user using passport.js. But now how do I insert a data to my database? Do I need to use passport.js to add new user?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Node.js ,Mongoose and MongoDB , you can follow the steps mentioned in this blog to perform CRUD operations=> [Getting Started : CRUD with Mongoose,MongoDB,Node.js](http://blog.modulus.io/getting-started-with-mongoose)